# How can I achieve this whitish circular pattern?

Tags: photoshop-effects, gradient, effects

[image]

I am trying to achieve this whitish circular pattern at the back of pizza giving a glowing effect. I have tried Gradients but the Circular gradient isn't giving me this effect. Please, I need help. I googled it but I can't figure out the name of this glowing whitish circular pattern to get specific result i want from google.

Comment: The gradient tool set to a circular gradient can be used for this. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: @BillyKerr I am trying to do that but the Circular gradient color's the whole layer not giving me this circular pattern but a simple color layer (lighter tone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a foreground colour that's slightly lighter, and a background colour that's slightly darker. Then select the first gradient in the drop down (the Foreground to Background gradient). Then make your circular gradient by clicking and dragging from the centre outwards towards the corner, but not beyond the edge of the canvas.

[image]

Comment: I am trying this but the circular lines don't show.  I am trying to uplaod a picture but in add comment section there is no attachment option

Comment: Like when you draw it shows circular closed lines fading away from center. In my case its just a big white color fading away to dark colo.

Comment: What circular lines?  I can't see any in the example you posted.  If you want to share an image in a comment, you need to upload it to imgur and copy and paste the link.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, man. I have figured out the problem. It was about the location and spread of lighter color in the gradient.  :)

Comment: @ArJami, are you talking about [Color Banding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding)?

Answer (score 1):

An old case, but still there's some room for variations

You can make a selection and fill it with brighter color in a new layer:

[image]

(sorry for my bad quality screenshots)

Then you can blur the new layer to get something that resembles a gradient:

[image]

You can reduce the layer opacity for more subtle effect:

[image]

But why? This seems complex when compared to a gradient??

Right, but you can have any selection shape, there's no need to use a circle. An example - a blurred triangle:

[image]

BTW. The pink triangle and the shadow were initially magic wand selections that contained the slice area. The emptiness around the slice was selected and the selection was inverted.